# Gcloud Run - Find latest revision's name

Tags: gcloud

I'm trying to find the name of the latest revision of a gcloud run service, so that I can change its assigned traffic when running a Jenkins pipeline. I've tried the [gcloud run revisions list](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/revisions/list) with the `--limit`, `--sort-by`, `--format` flags, but I'm not getting what I expected. When limiting to only one result, the second to last revision comes up instead of the latest one. Am I doing anything wrong?

The following are the `gcloud` commands I've ran coupled with their output.

```sh
>gcloud run revisions list --service service-foo --platform managed --region europe-west4 --limit 2 --sort-by ~creationTimestamp --format="value(name,creationTimestamp)"
service-foo-00302-luq     2021-08-27T11:13:39.883161Z
service-foo-00300-san     2021-08-26T15:45:33.351646Z

>gcloud run revisions list --service service-foo --platform managed --region europe-west4 --limit 1 --sort-by ~creationTimestamp --format="value(name,creationTimestamp)"
service-foo-00300-san     2021-08-26T15:45:33.351646Z

>gcloud run revisions list --service service-foo --platform managed --region europe-west4 --limit 1 --sort-by creationTimestamp --format="value(name,creationTimestamp)"
service-foo-00300-san     2021-08-26T15:45:33.351646Z
```

Comment: Curious! You're not doing anything wrong. Not that it's the correct solution (!) but it may be a solution, what happens if you drop the `--sort-by` entirely?

Comment: @DazWilkin Dropping `--sort-by` results in the same output:

>gcloud run revisions list --service service-foo --platform managed --region europe-west4 --limit 2 --format="value(name,creationTimestamp)"
service-foo-00300-san     2021-08-26T15:45:33.351646Z
service-foo-00302-luq     2021-08-27T11:13:39.883161Z

>gcloud run revisions list --service service-foo --platform managed --region europe-west4 --limit 1 --format="value(name,creationTimestamp)"
service-foo-00300-san     2021-08-26T15:45:33.351646Z

Since you're saying this isn't the best solution, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your solution is the correct approach.... My suggestion to drop the `--sort-by` wasn't a great solution since the command ought to work with or without it.

Comment: It's not quick to repro you issue.... Perhaps this is one time when you should use a complementary tool... perhaps pipe the `--format=json` into `jq` and query there?

Comment: There is a `date()` projection too... It may help to convert `creationTimestamp` to seconds, `--format="json(name, creationTimestamp.date(format='%s'))"`

Comment: Looks like you have a bug related to the SDK, I've opened a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/199704948) in their Issue Tracker so they can work on it. I would recommend you to star it to track the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There **does** seem to currently be a bug for the `revisions` subgroup's `list` command using both the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) SDK (`gcloud`):

```sh
gcloud run revisions list \
--format="value(metadata.name)" \
--platform=managed \
--region=$CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_REGION \
--service=$CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME \
--sort-by="~metadata.creationTimestamp"

#=>

$CLOUD_RUN_LATEST_REVISION
$CLOUD_RUN_PREVIOUS_REVISION
. . .
```

when using the `--limit` flag:

```sh
gcloud run revisions list \
--format="value(metadata.name)" \
--limit=1 \
--platform=managed \
--region=$CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_REGION \
--service=$CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME \
--sort-by="~metadata.creationTimestamp"

#=>

$CLOUD_RUN_PREVIOUS_REVISION
```

and the GCP REST API with the `limit` query param.:

```sh
curl \
--location \
--request GET "https://$CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_REGION-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/revisions?limit=1" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"

#=>

{
  . . .
  "items": [
    {
      . . .
      "metadata": {
        "name": "$CLOUD_RUN_PREVIOUS_REVISION",
        . . .
      },
      . . .
    },
    . . .
  ]
}
```

with the latest `gcloud` version:

```sh
gcloud version

#=>

Google Cloud SDK 357.0.0
. . .
```

However, there **is** a way to get both the latest *created* and *ready* revisions of a Cloud Run service using the `services` subgroup instead of the `revisions` subgroup:

```sh
gcloud run services describe $GCLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME \
--format="value(status.latestCreatedRevisionName)" \
--platform=managed \
--region=$CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_REGION

#=>

$CLOUD_RUN_LATEST_REVISION
```

and:

```sh
gcloud run services describe $GCLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME \
--format="value(status.latestReadyRevisionName)" \
--platform=managed \
--region=$CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_REGION

#=>

$CLOUD_RUN_LATEST_REVISION
```

You can read more about the `describe` command for the `services` subgroup [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/services/describe).